# Скрипт получения возможных комбинаций между числами (датами). [PHP]

Tags: php

Задача следующая, имеется сайт, который делает выборку по определенным параметрам (год от и до и пара других фильтров, но необходим конкретно год) из базы данных, база данных весит более 50 ГБ, за пару месяцев или пару лет выборка может занимать больше время, соответственно нужно кэшировать локально (сохранять данные выборки в файл кэша).

Для кэширования страниц необходимо сделать множество запросов со всеми возможными комбинациями дат. Запрос даты выглядит следующим образом 2021-01/2022-03, соответственно при таком запросе мы получим данные начиная с 2021-01 и по 2022-03, мне необходимо написать скрипт, который получит всевозможные комбинации даты по годам и месяцам, пример:

```
2021-01 / 2021-01,
2021-01 / 2021-02,
2021-01 / 2021-03,
2021-01 / 2021-04,
.....
.....
.....
2021-01 / 2022-01,
2021-01 / 2022-02,
2021-01 / 2022-03,
.....
.....
.....
2021-03 / 2022-03,
2021-03 / 2022-04,
2021-03 / 2022-05
```

и так далее. Каким способом это можно реализовать на PHP, к примеру через цикл? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Смог написать небольшой скрипт, возможно кому нибудь пригодится:

```
try {

        $startDate = '2020-01';
$endDate = '2022-01';
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($startDate),
    new DateInterval('P1M'),
    new DateTime($endDate)
);

$map = array_map(
    static function ($item) {
        return $item->format('Y-m');
    }, iterator_to_array($datePeriod)
);

foreach ($map as $key => $date) {
    $dateArray[] = [
        'start' => $date
    ];
}

$x = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($dateArray as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($map as $keys => $date) {

        $startsDate = strtotime('+' . $x . ' MONTH', strtotime($startDate));
        if(str_replace('-', '', $value['start']) === str_replace('-', '', $date)) {
            continue;
        }

        if(str_replace('-', '', $value['start']) > str_replace('-', '', $date)) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $result[] = [
            'start' => str_replace('-', '', $value['start']) . '-'  . str_replace('-', '', $date)
        ];
    }
    $x++;
}


    var_dump($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Скрипт выводит данные в нужном мне формате, то есть дата вида "202103-202103", можно убрать в последнем цикле str_replace и/или, если необходимы данные по дням, то в 7-й строке скрипта необходимо заменить ход с месяца, на день (P1D) и  везде где дата формата Y-m добавить вывод дня (Y-m-d).